# Why "K".Length gives me wrong result?

Tags: c#, string, string-length

I am seeing this strange issue, and can't find anything similar to this anywhere on the web:

```
int l = "K".Length;    //This actually returns 2 !!! The 'Autos' window in
                       //the debugger also shows "K".Length as 2.

string s = "K";
l = s.Length;          //Whereas this returns 1 as expected
```

I tried this in various C# projects and even asked another developer to confirm the behaviour is identical in a different project on a different machine.

I tried the same in VB.NET:

```
Dim l As Integer = "K".Length    'This returns 1 correctly
```

Am I loosing it?

Comment: Debugger's quickwatch's `"K".Length` shows 1.

Comment: Debugger's immediate's `"K".Length` shows 1.

Comment: I think you are loosing it. The reason that your string has a length of 2 is that it contains two chars.

Comment: Isn't that a space before K in the first example? :)

Comment: I ran the same code and both returned as 1. Very mysterious. Are you using some kind of special compiler? That result really is baffling.

Comment: You're expecting the first one, with the special character, to return `1`?

Comment: Ok, its not a `K` its a special character

Comment: VB.NET also shows 2: http://ideone.com/2ZqdS9  C#: http://ideone.com/ccCI4x

Comment: `int l = "K".Length;`  returns `1` on my machine (Turkey). Could be a _Culture_ thing?

Comment: @SonerGönül: You have to copy/paste _his_ K. It contains another character which you can see here: http://ideone.com/1LmYhP

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah, it contains `▲` and `K`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because "K", unlike "K", has an invisible character in it, namely an ascii value of 30 (record separator).

You can verify this by doing

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("K");
```

Comment: Now the question, how did this Magical "K" appear?

Comment: I think the difference is who copypasted the code sample, and who typed it out themselves...

Comment: Yes you are right! I was just about to post the same. I believe the issue came in when I copied some text from some .txt log file to build up parts of a communication packet in code. I honestly thought the Visual Studio editor would only allow printable text on paste - as I believe would make sense... Now I know it also accepts non-printable characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your "K" actually contains two characters. One "K" and the other unicode invisible symbol. When I type clearly `"-K-"` it shows 1, when I copy-paste your code, it is 2. Paste it twice and it will be 4.